# AJAX Not Sending Data to Web API Controller

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, webapi

The following Ajax code doesn't even trigger my action if the input variable `a` isn't set to Null.

Ajax code:

```
var ab = "Chocolate Smoothies ya know?";

$("#customerSubmit").submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Booking/lander",
        method: "post",
        data: { a: ab }
    })
});
```

The following my controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public void lander(string a)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(a);
}
```

And when I do not set it to null, the input received is null.

screenshot when the breakpoint is triggered:

[image]

I've used type/method/etc.. Nothing seems to work

Update:

I even tried the following but no use:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From my experience when you use Post method it is better to use some class wrapper like:

```
public class StringInfo
{
     public string Value {get; set; }
}

public void lander(StringInfo info)
```

And in your javascript

```
data: { value: ab }
```

Comment: It didn't work... I copied both your Controller and Ajax code.. no effect

Comment: Moreover, I got this: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Answer (score -1):

When you post simple types Using WebAPI on C# it automaticaly binds it to the Url, so change your [FromBody] in the controller to [FromURI]

Alternativly you can pass it as a complex type with a empty variable name

```
var ab = 'Chocolate Smoothies ya Know?';
$.ajax({
    url:"/api/Booking/lander", 
    data: {'': ab}
});
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)